# Redistribute messages from a stucked kafka partiton

Tags: apache-kafka, partition

I have a topic descibed in kafka as below ( *via `/usr/hdp/2.6.5.0-292/kafka/bin/kafka-topics.sh --describe <rest of command>`* )

```
Topic:arrival_events    PartitionCount:12   ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:

Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 0    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1002 Isr: 1001,1002
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 1    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003 Isr: 1002,1003
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 2    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001 Isr: 1003,1001
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 3    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1003 Isr: 1003,1001
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 4    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001 Isr: 1002,1001
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 5    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002 Isr: 1003,1002
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 6    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1002 Isr: 1001,1002
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 7    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003 Isr: 1002,1003
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 8    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001 Isr: 1003,1001
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 9    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1003 Isr: 1003,1001
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 10   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001 Isr: 1002,1001
Topic: arrival_events   Partition: 11   Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002 Isr: 1003,1002
```

Broker recives roughly `5-8mil` messages (travel patterns) a days. 
Everything is fine except that couple of partitions ( not more than 2-3 ) are stucked with high lag. 
With continuous flow of data, over days, this some times goes beyond 1-2mill as well. While other partitions sit comfortably at 0 lag

I have tried bringing down consumer count to less than 12 assuming that `round robin` will force reading up for other partitions too but it doesn't help.

Any suggestion on what option do I have to reduce this lag? Consumers are through a data streaming processor built using java.

Comment: Do the messages in your topic have non-null message key?

Comment: Also, please add more info on the outcome of these two commands if possible. 1) `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <broker>:9092 --describe --group <consumer-group-name>`. 2) `bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server <broker>:9092 --describe --group <consumer-group-name> --members --verbose`

Comment: How many consumers do you have in the consumer group?

Answer (score 1):

If the messages have non-null message keys, then probably the partitions which have high lag are getting more data than the rest. In that case, it might be beneficial to force a round robin partitioning scheme, irrespective of the keys, if it doesn't have any implication on the business logic.